# I gettting error when create project by locklift

Tags: everscale

I have installed locklift by following comand:

```
npm install --save-dev locklift
```

then i trying to create project by

```
npx locklift init -f
```

or getting version by

```
npx locklift --version
```

and always getting following error:

```
C:\projects\everscale\locklift\node_modules\locklift\internal\config\index.js:123
        throw new commander_1.default.InvalidOptionArgumentError(`Config at ${configPath} not found!`);
              ^
InvalidArgumentError: Config at locklift.config.ts not found!
```

```
after it, i created "locklift.config.ts" with contain from https://www.npmjs.com/package/locklift (Configuration)

but anyway i getting following error:
```

Path:
Error: Expected the value to satisfy a union of `object | object`, but received: undefined

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your report. Please upgrade your locklift to version 2.4.3 (the latest). Actually, repeat your steps